# Java Modules in a Java Web application

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, module, httpclient

I am developing a web application using JSF 2.3. I need to create a Servlet which makes an HTTP connection to an URL and get a JSON object and process it. There are many third party APIs available for this sake, but I am more interested in using HttpClient which comes default in JDK11 onwards.

But the problem I face here is, I cannot use HttpClient without modularizing i.e. defining it as a requirement in module-info.java for my application. And, if I define module-info.java I can't get servlet classes reference resolved in my code. javax.* dependencies and other third party dependencies are not resolved. All the required libraries are present. So my question is

**Q1. How can I use HttPClient in a Java web application with servlets, and JSF framework?**
**Q2. How do I resolve third party dependencies in a moduler java application?**

I am using Payara server 5, JDK-11, RHEL 7.9

Comment: You should be able to use `HttpClient` without creating a `module-info.java` as the unnamed module automatically requires anything.

Comment: And basically, your IDE will tell you what modules are missing and the modules are declared in the `module-info.java` of the dependencies or (if the file does not exist) automatically generated.

Comment: @dan1st ,  I know that IDE complains about it, If I add httpclient via module-info, I don't have access to servlet apis. And if I don;t use module-info then i don't have HttpClient directly.

Comment: Does your IDE suggest you what modules to import when complaining about the servlet APIs? What IDE do you use? Is it possible that the IDE switches to Java < 8 when you remove the `module-info.java`?

Comment: @dan1st, I am using Netbeans 12.0, and it doesn't suggest any module name to define in module-info.java. It shows just a small list of modules. I am using Java-11. I think I would like to mention it clearly again in below points - 1. I have a working JSF2.3 project where I want to use HttpClient to make an external connection. When I try to import the pacakge, my IDE doesn't find it. After looking on the material on Internet when I defined module-info.java and declares that I need java.net.http, I could get HttpClient imports. But now I could not get javax.servlet.*,

Comment: @dan1st, I have no idea what to put into module-info.java to import javax.servlet.*. 2. If i remove module-info.java again, all other imports including javax.servlet.* works, but I don;t have access to Httpclient. I hope I made it clear.